# How can I call Perl from my PHP page on apache?

Tags: php, perl, cgi

my friend and I are creating a log parser for a series of games. We have written the frontend (web) in PHP/MySQL and the parser in Perl (also using MySQL, of course). Now we are having problems getting these two to communicate.

All we wan't to do is this: one administration page online where you have the button "parse". When you click this a Perl script should start. Like "exec("perl /home/www/Init.pm -f games_mp.log").

Is this possible? Remember, it's suppose to be easy to set up.

We've tried everything from system/exec to .htaccess, but nothing seems to work out of the box. Not working at all really.

Suggestions?

laka =)

Comment: What error do you get when you try to run that system()/exec() call?

Comment: Wait, you are getting a 403 Forbidden error when calling exec? I don't think the exec/system is your problem.

Comment: Isn't the problem that apache is not allowed to run the script?

Comment: Well, if you are getting a 403 Forbidden back, which is an HTTP error code, it sounds like the request isn't hitting PHP at all. Check your apache error log.

Comment: I'm not trying to hit PHP - but Perl. And I'm not in control of the server so I can't read any logs..

Comment: Oh, well then I apologize for my misunderstanding. I got the impression that you were calling Perl from a PHP page using the exec command.

Comment: What file is this exec() call in, then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry to say there's no easy way to set this up. Different servers come with different default apache configs.

What you're probably looking to do is add the following line inside the either the server config, virtual host config, directory config, or, if properly setup, .htaccess.

`AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .pm`

Your users will also need to chmod and chown the files appropriately.

Thing is, this sounds like a long running process. If it is, then it might take so long to run the web browser will time out before it is done. If that's the case, you'll likely want to setup some kind of job queue and have a cron script exec based off that every 5 min or so.

Comment: Damn.. I would have written it all in PHP if I knew it would be this hard to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Why not run the Perl script as if they were a web page from jQuery using mod_perl?

Comment: Because like I said, this is suppose to work out of the box.. not many gamers willing to install mod_perl..

Answer (score 1):

I'm willing to bet you are running into pathing errors. Try providing the full path to the Perl executable. For example:

```
exec("/usr/bin/perl /home/www/Init.pm -f games_mp.log")
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP many things depend on configuration. Try looking into it as many operators can be disabled.

Check that Perl program has correct rights. Try running you Perl program from command line.